# Problema al insertar nuevos elementos en array multidimensional en PHP

Tags: php, array

Tengo el siguiente problema, al intentar meter un nuevo alumno en el array me recarga la página y no lo inserta. Tengo unos datos ya en el array y un formulario muy sencillo para insertar un nuevo elemento.

```
<?php session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    $_SESSION = [];
}

function precargados(){
  $aNotas = [];
  $aNombre = [];
  $aApellido = [];

    $aNombre[0] = "Eugenio";
    $aApellido[0] = "Martínez";
    $aNotas[0] = [8,5,7.5,3.2,9];

    $aNombre[1] = "Marta";
    $aApellido[1] = "Carrera";
    $aNotas[1] = [9.5,5,6.4,6];

    $aNombre[2] = "Nacho";
    $aApellido[2] = "Herrera";
    $aNotas[2] = [5,8,3.8,8];

    $aNombre[3] = "Anxo";
    $aApellido[3] = "Iglesias";
    $aNotas[3] = [6,7,4.5,3.5];

    $aNombre[4] = "Valentina";
    $aApellido[4] = "Iglesias";
    $aNotas[4] = [3.5,8,5.5,2.8];

    $_SESSION['nombre'] = $aNombre;
    $_SESSION['apellido'] = $aApellido;
    $_SESSION['notas'] = $aNotas;
}
```

Este sería el formulario y la función para añadir elementos al array:

```
function crearform(){
    echo "<div id='formulario'>
        <h3>Alta Alumno</h3><form action='index.php' method=POST>
                        <table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='15%'>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width='11%'>Nombre </td>
                                    <td width='10%'><input type='text' id='nombre' name='nombre'></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width='11%'>Apellido </td>
                                    <td width='10%'><input type='text' id='apellido' name='apellido'></td>
                                    </tr>
                                        <td width='10%'><input type='submit' name='enviar' id='enviar' value='Crear alumno'/>
                                    </tr>
                        </table>
                    </form></div>";}

function creaAlumno(){
  if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['nombre']) && !empty($_POST['apellido'])){
      $nuevaNota['notas'] = [];
      $nuevoNombre['nombre'] = $_POST['nombre'];
      $nuevoApellido['apellido'] = $_POST['apellido'];
      $nuevoAlumno = [$nuevoNombre['nombre'], $nuevoApellido['apellido'], $nuevaNota['notas']];
      array_push($_SESSION['nombre'], $_POST['nombre']);
      array_push($_SESSION['apellido'], $_POST['apellido']);
      array_push($_SESSION['notas'], $nuevaNota);
    }
  } else {
    echo "<script>alert ('Debe rellenar ambos campos para crear un alumno';)</script>";
  }
}
```

Como ya indiqué al hacer submit en el formulario, la página se recarga pero no guarda los datos en el array.
Gracias y saludos.

Comment: Podría ser que te añada el usuario, pero que al recargar la página se ejecute la función precargados() y este te vuelva a iniciar la sessión de usuairo.

Comment: En la función **creaAlumno()** insertas los datos del alumno en la sesión, pero no veo en tu código ningún sitio en donde la llames.

Comment: @PHPMyguel Tengo una función anterior con un sencillo login, que una vez se verifica la clave y el usuario lanza las demás funciones:       if(isset($_POST['enviarLogin'])){
    if($_POST['usuario'] == 'user' && $_POST['contrasenha'] == '123'){
      echo "<style>#login{display:none;}</style>";
      idSesion();
      precargados($aNombre, $aApellido, $aNotas);
      crearform();
      imprimeListado();
      utilidades();
      creaAlumno();
      echo "<script>alert('Bienvenidx!')</script>";
    }else{
      echo "<script>alert('Credenciales incorrectas')</script>";
    }
  }
}

Comment: Buenas. No veo que tengas un session_start() por ningún lado, por lo que, por mucho que lo metas en el array, si no inicias sesión no te va a funcionar. Saldrán los ´$_SESSION['nombre'] = $aNombre; $_SESSION['apellido'] = $aApellido;
    $_SESSION['notas'] = $aNotas;´ vacios y no mostrará nada. Prueba a hacerles un echo a ver que contienen.

Comment: @Emerita Buenas. Soy nuevo y no quería copiar todo el código de la aplicación. Ahoram mismo edito la pregunta y muestro más para que sea más claro el código. Gracias.

Comment: No te preocupes. A veces poco código está bien, pero en tu caso poco es igual a mal jejejeje. Necesitamos saber si cargas la sesión, que tienes en el index.php y esas cosillas que procesan el código. Es decir, piensa que el código recorre un camino y nosotros necesitamos conocer ese camino para ver donde tropieza. No necesitamos toda la aplicación, solo el recorrido de lo que da error.

Comment: @Emerita Realmente no hay mucho más. Simplemente en el momento de hacer submit en el form, me vuelve al login y no guarda los datos en la sesión. El resto del código está comentado hasta que resuelva esta cuestión. Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Ahh! que no te lo guarda en la variable de sesión. Pues entonces recoge los datos en una variable, pásalo a la variable de sesión y hazle el push al array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que todo te resulte mas sencillo puedes manejar toda la información de los alumnos en un solo `array` de `arrays`, de esta manera:

```
<?php session_start();
// Esto no se con que fin lo hagas
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    $_SESSION = [];
}

function precargados() {
    $alumnos = (object)array(
        array(
            "nombre" => "Eugenio",
            "apellido" => "Martínez",
            "notas" => [8, 5, 7.5, 3.2, 9],
        ),
        array(
            "nombre" => "Marta",
            "apellido" => "Carrera",
            "notas" => [9.5, 5, 6.4, 6],
        ),
        array(
            "nombre" => "Nacho",
            "apellido" => "Herrera",
            "notas" => [5, 8, 3.8, 8],
        ),
        array(
            "nombre" => "Anxo",
            "apellido" => "Iglesias",
            "notas" => [6, 7, 4.5, 3.5],
        ),
        array(
            "nombre" => "Valentina",
            "apellido" => "Iglesias",
            "notas" => [3.5, 8, 5.5, 2.8],
        ),
    );
    $_SESSION['alumnos'] = $alumnos;
}
```

Con esto puedes acceder a tus registro mas fácil, actualmente te lo puse con objetos, pero si no sabes usar objetos puedes quitarle el `(object)` y listo.

Tu formulario queda bien así:

```
<div id='formulario'>
    <h3>Alta Alumno</h3>
    <form action='index.php' method=POST>
        <table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='15%'>
            <tr>
                <td width='11%'>Nombre</td>
                <td width='10%'><input type='text' id='nombre' name='nombre'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width='11%'>Apellido</td>
                <td width='10%'><input type='text' id='apellido' name='apellido'></td>
            </tr>
            <td width='10%'><input type='submit' name='enviar' id='enviar' value='Crear alumno'/></tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

Si tienes tu formulario en el mismo archivo donde procesas la información puedes hacerlo directamente sin hacer una función:

```
if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['nombre']) && !empty($_POST['apellido'])) {
        $data = array(
            'notas' => array(),
            'nombre' => $_POST['nombre'],
            'apellido' => $_POST['apellido'],
        );
        $_SESSION['alumnos'][] = $data;
    }
} else {
    echo "<script>alert ('Debe rellenar ambos campos para crear un alumno';)</script>";
}
```

Ya cuando quieras acceder a algún alumno puedes hacer un `foreach()` para recorrer el `array principal` y cada `array hijo` es un alumno y accedes por el nombre de su propiedad (nombre, apellido y notas).